# getting xml child in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get to to the items child in XML using javascript.

The rss file is: Can i use dot syntax? item.title? I'mg etting undefined in the code below

`<item>
<title><link>`

> $(document).ready(function(){     alert =
>   console.log;
>
> ```
>   var ns = {
> ```

```
    init : function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/calendar/RSSSyndicator.aspx?type=N&number=15&category=8-0%2c4-0%2c6-0%2c10-0%2c7-0%2c17-0%2c16-0%2c9-0%2c5-0%2c3-0%2c2-0&department=3&numdays=31&ics=Y&rsstitle=Annandale+-+Event+Listing&rssid=11',
            success: this.loaded                
        });
    }, 

    loaded: function(data){
        // Get access to the events id in the DOM
        var events = document.getElementById('events');

        // Get item from the RSS document
        var items = data.getElementsByTagName('item');
    alert('test');



    }

}



ns.init();
```

});

Comment: alert(items[0].title.childNodes[0].nodeValue);  is getting undefined also.

Comment: another question -  var events = document.getElementById('events');  Do i need to specify var? it's just a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to debug issues like this is to load up the page in firefox after installing the [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) plugin. In this plugin, you can set a breakpoint, and then inspect the items variable and see what properties and structure the object has.

Alternatively, if you are open to it, you can load up the XML into a [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) object and then use those facilities to navigate the DOM.

Comment: The only way you can get an XML document with jQuery is by downloading it via Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

No, unless you're using [E4X](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/E4X/Processing_XML_with_E4X) you can't use dot notation to navigate an XML DOM in JavaScript. You'll have to use standard DOM: `getElementsByTagName("title")`, `childNodes` etc.

E4X does let you navigate XML as though it were a JavaScript object tree, but of the main browsers it is only supported in Firefox.

Comment: Great. I think that's where i was getting confused. I'll stick to the dom methods.